# Check if there is a "1" in column, if there is, then filter

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that allows me to search for a string and if it's there, then filter for that string but if it's not there then don't do anything.

```
Dim Findvalue As String
Dim Rng As Range
Findvalue = "1"

 With ws.Range("K:K")
      Set Rng = .Find(What:=Findvalue, _
                  After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                  LookIn:=xlValues, _
                  LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                  MatchCase:=False)
             If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                  ws.Range("K4").AutoFilter _
                  Field:=11, _
                  Criteria1:="1"

             Else
                Exit Sub
             End If
 End With
```

This works if the value is a letter but doesn't work when it's a number.

Comment: Then `FindValue` should be a `Variant`.

Comment: @BigBen Changed `Dim FindValue As Variant`, still same issue.

Comment: Did you change `"1"` to `1`?

Comment: Are you getting error 1004? If you are then you would want to change ```Field:=11``` to ```Field:=1```.

Answer (score 2):

The find method often has format-related problems; you can try with

```
Dim Findvalue As String

Findvalue = "1"
With ws
   If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("K:K"), Findvalue) > 0 Then
        .Range("K4").AutoFilter _
        Field:=11, _
        Criteria1:="1" 'Criteria1:=Findvalue ?
   End If
End With
```

Comment: Side note: you would still want `Findvalue` to be a `Variant` and `1` instead of `"1"`.

Comment: Of course! but the OP could have its reasons for using a string; the code with CountIf works in both cases.

Comment: Yes. Since OP was using a number, I figured an answer should, well, use a number. But I do like CountIf over Find here, upvoted.

Comment: It still doesn't filter, I tried changing `Findvalue` to be a `Variant`, and `1` instead of `"1"`. Even tried doing `Criteria1:= Findvalue`. I'm not getting any errors, it just won't do anything.